# Iterate over two lists and filter the results in Java 8 using stream

Tags: stream, java-stream

I have 2 lists:

List list1;
List list2;

I need to filter the results using both the lists such that records in list2 lies between date range in list1.

Comment: What is unclear to you in terms of the Streams library?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you want to do here. I can suggest this solution for Integer numbers:

```
List<Integer> borders = Arrays.asList(2, 8);
List<Integer> rawNumbers = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
List<Integer> result = rawNumbers.stream()
                                 .filter(e -> e > borders.get(0))
                                 .filter(e -> e < borders.get(1))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```